# How to solve the date range search using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, apache, codeigniter, xampp

**Controller code**

```
public function getcari(){

    $tglawal=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('tgl1', TRUE)));
    $tglakhir=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('tgl2', TRUE)));
    $data['detail']=$this->traffic_model->cari($tglawal,$tglakhir); 
    $this->load->view('daftar_traffic', $data); //menampilkan data yang sudah dicari
}
```

**Model Code**

```
function cari($tglawal,$tglakhir){      

$this->db->select('DATE_FORMAT(tgl, %d %M %Y) AS tanggal,COUNT(IF(kategori.parent=35 , VALUE, NULL)) AS Software,  COUNT(IF(kategori.parent=33 , VALUE, NULL)) AS Indent,  COUNT(IF(kategori.parent=32 , VALUE, NULL)) AS Ready, COUNT((DATE_FORMAT(tgl, %d - %m - %Y))) AS Total'); //changed the code here from COUNT(clients.id) AS num_rows
$this->db->from('masalah ');
$this->db->where('DATE(masalah.tgl) >=', $tglawal);
$this->db->where('DATE(masalah.tgl) <=', $tglakhir);
$this->db->join('kategori, kategori.kategori=masalah.kategori', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('tanggal');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

**View Code**

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('traffic/getcari');?>" method="post"><input type="date" name="tgl1" palceholder="Input date" requaried="true" /> <input type="date" name="tgl2" palceholder="Input date" requaried="true" /><button type="submit">Cari</button> <a href="<?php echo site_url('traffic'); ?>" style="text-decoration:none; color: black;">Reset</a>
```

> the errors... Warning:
>   include(C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function cari() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\application\modules\traffic\controllers\traffic.php
>   on line 24
>
> Warning:
>   include(C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269
>
> Warning:
>   include(C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\portalacw\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269 '

pleas help me

Comment: well, for one, it seems you deleted your error views. should be a folder in views called `errors` or something similar. if you dont have it download it from a fresh copy of CI and place it in the views folder.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, your problem is because you didn't load the model correctly.
So your controller took the `traffic_model` to be `null`.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Can you help me?
What should I do?

Comment: Before using the model, you should load the model.

Comment: this is code for load to model $data['detail']=$this->traffic_model->cari($tglawal,$tglakhir);

Comment: It should be something like this: $this->load('Traffic_Model', 'traffic_model');

Comment: Will you give the url of your testing page so that I can see your error messages directly?